# How would I properly formulate "Save to and read from <an item>"

Tags: syntactic-analysis

In the context of answering a question on Stack Overflow:

> Save to and read from the file that JSON string.

It's pretty clumsy, but I want to express that you altogether save to and read from. Using...

> Save and read that JSON string from the file
>
> Save that JSON string to and from the file

...is actually wrong, as one doesn't save from a file, nor read to a file. Hence "Save to and read from" but that JSON string breaks everything.

Is there a proper way to use that formulation in this case?

Comment: I think *Save and read that JSON string from the file* sounds correct.

Comment: I would say "save the JSON string to a file, then read it from there".

Comment: If there's nothing else in the file people regularly speak of json files.

Comment: It's a question of writing advice and so could be OT.

Comment: @Kris No, it’s a question of grammar. Asking how to combine a direct object shared between two coordinated phrasal verbs that have different prepositions which also share a prepositional object—and still produce a grammatical sentence—has nothing to do with writing advice.

Comment: Not your question, but "JSON string" isn't really correct. It's either JSON or JSON object. Normally on SO you would just say something like "you can save/read JSON from the file", because conciseness and clarity is valued more than strict grammar rules.

Comment: @jimm101 what do you think is JSON? Yeah, some folks prefer call it an 'object' but it *really* is simply a string, which you can encode using different character sets, and have nothing more to differentiate from other strings than it's construct. </off-topic> :)

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier. It ambiguous in a way that almost always matters. '{"this":"that"}' is a string, {"this":"that"} is JSON. You'd have to parse the first, not the second, to get a value from a key. If you're writing the string to the file, you'd write either '{"this":"that"}' or "{\"this\":\"that\"}. That matters if, for example, a function is expected to return a string or an object.

Comment: @jimm101 I don’t see what’s incorrect about “JSON string”. JSON is JavaScript Object Notation—i.e., it is a _notation system_. A string made up of text in a given notation is an _X notation string_, and a string made up of text in JavaScript Object Notation is thus a _JSON string_. Regardless of quotes, a parser always has to parse content expressed in JSON and written to a file in order to get an actual object out of it; it’s just a matter of how that parsing occurs.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yup, everything ascii or unicode is a string of characters, and that's the ambiguity. *String* is defined within the field as well, and has other baggage--either a null termination, a set of functions it works with--something. So writing a *string* to a file is ambiguous, whereas writing JSON is not. If you're looking for a reformulation, I'd remove "string" and the baggage it carries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way of doing what you’re after here in the narrowest terms.

The trouble is that you have two different, coordinated phrasal verbs with different prepositions (*save **to***, *read **from***), and both prepositions share an object (*the file*); but at the same time the two different verbs *also* share a direct object (*that JSON string*).

Either on its own is possible:

- If you get rid of the prepositional object, you’d also get rid of the prepositions themselves, and you’d end up with two simple verbs that share an object: *Save and read that JSON string*.
- If you get rid of the direct object, you have two coordinated phrasal verbs whose prepositions share an object: *Save to and read from the file*.

But the snag that you immediately hit when you try to combine the two is that the two objects want to occupy the same slot. When multiple verbal constructions share a complement, we normally place that complement after the last verbal unit—but there are *two* shared objects here, and you can’t place both of them after the last verbal unit, unless you write/say them on top of each other… which makes no sense.

The only solution is then to get rid of one of them by ‘unsharing’ it: repeat it in both verbal units. This does somewhat ruin the niceness of the shared object construction, but there is no helping that.

In this case (for reasons that I admit I can’t quite pin down off the top of my head), there is only one option: it must be the prepositional object (*that JSON string*) which is repeated, not the direct object (*the file*):

> Save that JSON string to and read it from the file.

That is still quite clumsy, and you’re not likely to hear anyone naturally say it, but it is grammatical. Just. If you wanted to express the same thing, but in a more natural way, you’d have to break up the construction even more and repeat *both* objects in both verbal units. Doing so with no further changes would yield a sentence that is, again, grammatical (just), but highly unidiomatic:

> Save that JSON string to the file and read it from it.

Having two identical pronouns in the same clause refer back to two different antecedents is not something English is fond of. A better rewrite would be what michael.hor257k suggests in his comment:

> Save that JSON string to the file, then read it from there.

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly the kind of analysis I was looking for, as I wasn't even close to put words on that.